# Xamarin Forms Play Asset Delivery

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-play-console, android-asset-delivery

I got a game app that is 600mb+ as `.aab`. Google Console wont let any upload higher than 150mb.

I need to somehow use `Play Asset Delivery` to get my assets to be `On Install Time` when the app gets installed it fetches the bundle of resources. I do not have a clue if this is possible in `Xamarin Forms`.

I have found this [GitHub Example](https://github.com/infinitespace-studios/XamarinLegacyDynamicAssetsExample) but its for `Xamarin.Android` which is most likely `Xamarin.Native` and most files are much different to the original files from `Xamarin.Forms`.

Is this possible in `Xamarin.Forms` and if so can someone help me out on how to achieve this, as my `raw` folder for videos and sounds is huge and wont even get close to 150mb even with compression. If I try huge compression I will lose a huge amount of quality for video and audio.

I've spent way other 4 hours now trying to figure this out and no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Linker to reduce the size of the application.

It has three options:

1. Don't Link (None in Visual Studio)
2. Link SDK Assemblies (Sdk Assemblies Only)
3. Link All Assemblies (Sdk and User Assemblies)

For more details, you can refer to this doc: [Linking on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker). Wish it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after trying to use Linker nothing drastic actually happened. In the end I made a decision to compress most of the files down. Not an optimal solution but it works for now until a better fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GitHub example you provided in Xamarin.Forms. It's the best way to create asset packs automatically during build.

However, if you want to do things manually, you can check this answer out:

[Adding Asset Packs to Android Bundle in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63886751/adding-asset-packs-to-android-bundle-in-xamarin/70423660#70423660)