# Xamarin bundle exceed 150

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Project (Android, iOS) with a large video (130mb) that make my bundle size exceeding 150mb. Is there any simple solution that not request a special modification in Android and iOS part of project to by pass this. I have

note: I have to publish this app in this 2 weeks => Im confused.

i did not undertand the post about Android Asset Delivery in Xamarin and what it afect the iOS part?

Comment: do you really need a large video embedded in your app?  Can you stream it or download it on demand?  Or can you resize it for embedding?

Comment: Yes, i do some compression and for now i have 158mb, it's the the max that i can tolerate for video quality.

Comment: If the answer below solved the issue, you could accept it. That may help others with same issues. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do it by reducing videos quality. It was the only think that i can do i my case (offline app).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aapt2 to package large assets and then use Play Asset Delivery to deliver them. You can do it either manually as shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423660/6129329

Or you can use MSBuild to do it automatically as shown here:

https://github.com/infinitespace-studios/XamarinLegacyDynamicAssetsExample