# How to Upload app bundle to google play console

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

In platform xamarin android i get a signed app bundle size of 400 mb when i tried to upload to google console
I get a message error that file is bigger than 150 mb
Thanks

Comment: Hi did you generate a signed bundled using the Release or Debug Mode? Debug bundles are always bigger because they are uncompressed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your assets to a separate asset pack (which is a special zip file) and use Play Asset Delivery (install time asset pack) to deliver them. About Play Asset Delivery:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery

**Solution 1.**
You can use MSBuild to achieve this as per this example:
https://github.com/infinitespace-studios/XamarinLegacyDynamicAssetsExample

**Solution 2.**
You can also do everything manually first and then attach the asset pack to your project, as per this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423660/6129329